# c - realloc() succeeds in Windows 7 but fails in Windows XP, why?

Tags: c, windows, memory-management

So this code of mine had the following `realloc` block:

```
char **ptr = NULL;

void realloc_ptr(unsigned int new_size)
{    
    void *temp = NULL;

    temp = realloc(ptr, new_size * sizeof(*ptr));

    if(temp != NULL) {
        ptr = temp;
    }
    else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

`new_size` is incremented right before this function is called. This array is always only expanded. Also, `new_size` never exceeds 3 in my code (for now).

Now the above `realloc` call worked fine during my testing in Windows 7. When I tested this code in XP, the above code would succeed 3 times and then it would throw an exception on the 4th time. I'll post the exact exception when I get back to the code (this computer doesn't have the code).

I'm guessing that my memory is too fragmented and the system could not allocate a contiguous block of memory. I have tested my code for memory leaks and fixed all of them (I hope). Any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

This above problem went away when I used Doug Lea's [malloc.c](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c). But I still want to know why this happened.

Thanks!

Comment: Offhand, what is `new_size` at the time you're doing this, and also, the memory mode in each config (64-bit vs. 32-bit).

Comment: Was there a 64-bit XP?

Comment: `new_size` would always be greater than the current size. I'm always expanding this array. Also what do you mean exactly by memory mode?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, it was offered later.

Comment: If you won't tell us what `new_size` is, how do you expect us to work out what the answer is? Why are you hiding details from us?

Comment: Since `ptr` is NULL, it is equivalent to `malloc()`. I have no idea why you are using `realloc()`

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. Hope that gives you the detail you need

Comment: @KonfleDolex, Oops, I overlooked that. Please see edited post. I'm so sorry.

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal, compilable testcase. Minimal means "using only enough code to reproduce the problem, without the confusion of irrelevant code", and compilable means "using enough code to compile on our systems without filling in the blanks or fixing errors".

Comment: And they said WindowsXP was better than Windows 7

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, edited the question again! Sorry.

Comment: @AnishRam That testcase is not compilable. Where is your main function?

Comment: I guess that `char** ptr` is an array of string. Did you do anything that make ptr invalid before calling `realloc_ptr()`? like `free(ptr)` ?

Comment: @KonfleDolex, no. This exact same code works in Windows 7 all the time for many test cases.

Comment: @AnishRam BTW, the problem is probably(>99%) due to memory leak. Most code should work on all platform.

Comment: @AnishRam I have run this code[ http://ideone.com/JqrA4P ] with `valgrind` . It reported no memory leak. The memory leak is likely occurred in elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I still see no minimal, compilable testcase. Will someone start a vote to close this under grounds that it can't be answered?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue, why is a compilable test case required? I'm asking for something concept related. Also, if my above problem goes away when I use Doug Lea's malloc, why is a compilable test case required?

Comment: @KonfleDolex, I guess I'll just have to go through the rest of the code. But why on earth would such a memory leak (if it exists) not cause issues in Windows 7?

Comment: @AnishRam If you don't provide a compilable testcase, then we can't rule out undefined behaviour prior to calling this code.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that `new_size` is just too large to be available in contiguous virtual memory. You can never ever be sure that a large amount of contiguous virtual memory is available on 32-bit systems.

You generally should try to use multiple smaller blocks and if possible not even alloc them all at the same time but alloc'ing the next after the previous was free'ed.

Comment: Hmm maybe I should try this approach. But when I used Doug Lea's [malloc.c](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c), this problem never occurred.

Comment: If windows has not enough contiguous virutal memory to offer then NO algorithm can provide it.

Comment: Maybe that realloc did exactly what you said in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> When I tested this code in XP, the above code would succeed 3 times and then it would throw an exception on the 4th time. I'll post the exact exception when I get back to the code (this computer doesn't have the code).

That (the exception) means you either have invalid pointers (or indices) somewhere (perhaps, uninitialized) and/or a memory corruption. `realloc()` must fail silently and return NULL if the request cannot be satisfied.

And it's perfectly normal to have different behavior on different OSes.