# c, doug lea's malloc - incorrect free does not crash. why?

Tags: c, crash, dynamic-allocation

I'm using Doug Lea's [malloc.c](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c) and [malloc.h](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.h) in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dlmalloc.h"

#define USE_DL_PREFIX

int main() 
{
    char *test = dlcalloc(5, 1);

    strcpy(test, "helloextra");    
    dlfree(test);                  /* Shouldn't this crash? */

    printf("%s", test);

    return 0;
}
```

And `test` prints correctly! Can someone please explain? I'm thinking that I haven't tuned this malloc right. Anybody had this problem before?

I started using Doug Lea's malloc after I had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919548/c-realloc-succeeds-in-windows-7-but-fails-in-windows-xp-why).

Comment: Why do you think it  should crash ?

Comment: I originally was of the opinion that this code was accessing invalid memory -> hence crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to crash, define FOOTERS, according to this snipped from [malloc.h](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c) you linked to:

> When FOOTERS is defined, in addition to range checking, we also
>   verify footer fields of inuse chunks, which can be used guarantee
>   that the mstate controlling malloc/free is intact.

At a quick glance, that *should* make `dlfree` to call `abort()`, if there has been buffer overrun.

Comment: Oh I knew I had overlooked some defintion. Thanks so much! I guess this answer most directly answers my question.

Comment: To be pedantic, since your code has undefined behaviour before it gets to `dlfree()`, it is permitted to misbehave in bizarre ways *before or instead of reaching `dlfree()`*.

Comment: Okay so is it possible to write code to detect such errors? My main reason for wanting it to crash is I know that I screwed up somewhere.

Comment: @NPE There's difference in being permitted to behave in bizarre ways, and there actually being a way to behave in bizarre ways in some particular case. In this case, there really is no way for the code to behave in bizarre ways with a regular PC operating system, it will either overwrite unused heap, or it will crash with segmentation fault. To have bizarre behaviour, code generally needs to corrupt something, and then some other code needs to use the corrupted value and because of it do something bizarre.

Comment: @AnishRam No, it's generally not possible. The valgrind tool can help you a great deal in discovering such errors though.

Comment: @hyde: I did say I was being pedantic. :) I am trying to help the OP to understand the meaning of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @nos To be fair, to *unintentionally* create buffer overflow, which is not detected by `dlfree`, is very unlikely. So I'd say more accurately: it is not possible to detect errors like this in 100% foolproof way, and it is not something to depend on, it's only a tool (as is valgrind) for better quality software.

Comment: @NPE Well, I guess I agree. An important point is also, just because one *thinks* to know what kind of "undefined behaviour" a particular construct will cause, does not mean being correct. This is true especially when optimizations are turned up for release build.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in `strcpy()`. It is permitted to crash, but not required to.

Basically, once the behaviour is undefined, *anything can happen*.

Comment: But this code crashes consistently when I use the `calloc` defined in `stdlib.h`

Comment: @AnishRam: Read up on undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AnishRam: It could also set your cat on fire. It's undefined behaviour, everything could happen, including giving the question to the Life, the Universe and Everything.

Comment: the decimal representation of SIGSEGFAULT is 42?

Comment: Haha thanks for that undefined behaviour article. Lots of unlearning to do now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are expecting the freeing of memory to also null the content, which is not the case. It would be way too inefficient. (think huge amounts of memory)

All that happens is that the blocks of memory are (again) marked as "being usable by malloc" and so their content could change at any time while other processes write to it, meaning "all bets are off", also known as "undefined behavior".

If you want the memory nulled, have a look at [memset](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset)